# *.VC.db в проекте Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

В проекте есть `*.VC.db` файл. Зачем он нужен?

Comment: Где это "в проекте"? Какая версия студии? У себя я таких файлов не наблюдаю.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36407386

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio начала создавать подобные файлы, начиная с версии VS2015 Update 2. Это база данных, нужная для работы автодополнения (IntelliSense); раньше она хранилась в файле `имя_проекта.sdf`.

Также, помимо файла `имя_проекта.VC.db`, студия создаёт и другой, скрытый файл с именем `projname.vc.vc.opendb`. Его задача — сигнализировать, что база уже кем-то используется.

Создание базы в новом формате поддерживалось и ранее, но только в экспериментальном режиме. Теперь же эта поддержка включена по умолчанию. Подобный переход ускорил работу IntelliSense примерно в два раза за счёт замены SQL Compact на более быстрый SQLite.

---

*<sup>Данный ответ является обобщённым переводом [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408065/2553424) пользователя [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034) на вопрос «What is the *.VC.db file in Visual Studio projects?»</sup>*

Comment: Вы хоть читаете, что публикуете? Или просто скопировали несогласованную словесную кашу из переводчика, нажали  «Отправить» и закрыли страницу? Пришлось открывать оригинал и переводить по-нормальному.